Interior gradient coloring of tcolorbox not working
I am using the modified IMSAloquium template. The following is my code
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage{setspace}  % <---
\setstretch{1.3}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{vanilla/.style=}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=cyan, fill=cyan!20]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{pointbackground.png}}
%------------------------------------------------------------

%Mergin selection%
\setbeamersize
{
    text margin left=0.7cm,
    text margin right=0.7cm
}
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the
%Title page





\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=blue,boxrule=0.5pt,top=0.7mm,bottom=0.7mm,grow to left by=5.8mm, grow to right by=5.9mm, before skip=0.07cm,
  interior style={left color=blue, right color=white}]
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\begin{document}



% Title Page
\frame{
\titlepage
}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
{
\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\includegraphics[width = \the\paperwidth, height = \the\paperheight]{toc.png}}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{pointbackground.png}}

\small
\begin{frame}{Cross section}
    
\end{frame}


%Bibilographies
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibilography}
    \bibliography{bibitems}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

At the frametitle boxes, it should give gradient coloring, as the manual is converned, but it is not. Why?

Add tcolorbox option enhanced.
From the tcolorbox package manual (v6.2.0, 2024-01-10), sec. 10.1 "Style Option Keys" (p. 172)

This option [/tcb/interior style] is available if the /tcb/interior titled engine→P. 157 or /tcb/interior engine→P. 158 is set to path, pathfirst, pathmiddle, or pathlast. It is not available for standard."

Initially, the /tcb/interior engine is standard. So to make interior style effective the minimum setting is interior engine=path.
The handy enhanced option is a shorthand for skin=enhanced, which sets /tcb/graphical environment=tikzpicture, all drawing engines (including /tcb/interior engine) to path, and more.
